# How to simplify repeating CASE statements containing subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I've built a query that satisfies the following logic:

1. For current month pull current values from table H joined on Material.
2. For previous 2023 months pull values from historic table HHistory joined on Material and Mth (HHistory is a monthly backup of table H with an additional Mth column. Months date back to January 2023).
3. For all other months prior to 2023 pull the oldest non-null value from HHistory regardless of Mth.

This is working perfectly for SqFt and runs in less than one second. But, I now need to expand this out for 30 other fields (labor, weight, etc...), and as soon as I try to do so the runtime quickly balloons. I'm wondering if I can restructure the CASE or even remove the subquery to increase performance as I add fields. I believe the subquery is what's causing the poor performance but I haven't figured out how to get the oldest value without it. Any thoughts?

```
SELECT 
    I.Mth, I.Material,

    SUM(I.Units) *  CASE 
                        WHEN MONTH(I.Mth) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(I.Mth) = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN H.SqFt 
                        WHEN YEAR(I.Mth) >= 2023 THEN HHistory.SqFt 
                        ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 SqFt FROM HHistory Sub WHERE Sub.Material = I.Material AND Sub.SqFt IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Sub.KeyID) 
                    END AS [Total SqFt],
    
    SUM(I.Units) *  CASE 
                        WHEN MONTH(I.Mth) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(I.Mth) = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN H.Labor
                        WHEN YEAR(I.Mth) >= 2023 THEN HHistory.Labor
                        ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 Labor FROM HHistory Sub WHERE Sub.Material = I.Material AND Sub.Labor IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Sub.KeyID) 
                    END AS [Total Labor],

    SUM(I.Units) *  CASE 
                        WHEN MONTH(I.Mth) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(I.Mth) = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN H.Weight
                        WHEN YEAR(I.Mth) >= 2023 THEN HHistory.Weight
                        ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 Weight FROM HHistory Sub WHERE Sub.Material = I.Material AND Sub.Weight IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Sub.KeyID) 
                    END AS [Total Weight]

-- Repeat for remaining 28 fields...

FROM I
    LEFT JOIN H ON I.Material = H.Material 
    LEFT JOIN HHistory ON I.Mth = HHistory.Mth AND I.Material = HHistory.Material
GROUP BY I.Material, I.Mth, H.SqFt, HHistory.SqFt
```

Table I (Units produced):

| Mth | Material | Units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 07-01-2020 | A | 100 |
| 03-01-2021 | A | 250 |
| 06-01-2022 | A | 175 |
| 04-01-2023 | A | 200 |
| 07-01-2023 | A | 300 |
| 08-01-2023 | A | 100 |

Table H (Current material table):

| Material | SqFt | Labor | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 30 | 2 | 6 |

Table HHistory (Monthly backup of H). Notice some fields may not have been tracked every month, so they could be NULL:

| Mth | Material | SqFt | Labor | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2023 | A | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 02-01-2023 | A | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 03-01-2023 | A | NULL | 1 | NULL |
| 04-01-2023 | A | NULL | 1.5 | NULL |
| 05-01-2023 | A | 25 | 1.5 | 5 |
| 06-01-2023 | A | 25 | 1.5 | 5 |
| 07-01-2023 | A | 30 | 2 | 6 |

Desired Results:

| Mth | Material | SqFt | Labor | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07-01-2020 | A | 2500 | 100 | 500 |
| 03-01-2021 | A | 6250 | 250 | 1250 |
| 06-01-2022 | A | 4375 | 175 | 875 |
| 04-01-2023 | A | NULL | 300 | NULL |
| 07-01-2023 | A | 7500 | 450 | 1500 |
| 08-01-2023 | A | 3000 | 200 | 600 |

Comment: some sample data and desired results would help here. Probably you could move the aggregation into a cross-apply.

Comment: You could probably pivot the history table once to create the last non-null values for every column and then join the whole big enchilada to get the values you need

Comment: Can you do a CTE of something like: SELECT FROM H UNION ALL SELECT FROM History WHERE Year = 2023 UNION ALL SELECT TOP 1 FROM History WHERE Year < 2023
then just sum that?  It seems like that would accomplish the same thing and be simpler to implement.

Comment: @hcaelxxam, the problem is (i'm guessing) that he wants last non null values which might come in different months

Comment: @siggemannen do they?  it looks to me like he wants a row of sum(units)*sqft for current month, each prior month from January 2023 forward, and then the last non-null value from pre-2023.  If I understand it right then a CTE of unions still feels like a simpler solution with the last non-null pre-2023 being the most complex part.  Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: @hcaelxxam but then he has weight. so he wanna do select top 1 weight ... where weight is not null, but maybe that weight won't be in same month as last non null sqft. But i don't know, proper test data would help out a lot here i'm thinking

Comment: @siggemannen so something like this for the last part of the cte? : SELECT TOP 1 FIRST_VALUE(sqft) OVER (PARTITION BY Material ORDER BY Mth), FIRST_VALUE(weight) ....

Comment: @hcaelxxam, yes, except it can't be NULL :)

Comment: @hcaelxxam updated with sample data, yes non-null values can come in different months. For example we may not have started tracking SqFt until later in the year.

Comment: @JackMorris, which sql server version do you use? if 2022, there are some simpler tools to handle your request

Comment: @JackMorris If I run that query with the data provided in your edit, the record in table I for June 2022 will get the Square Feet for something in 2023, as the subquery does not specify records before 2023.  Is that intentional?

It feels like the intent here is something to the effect of "Get the measurement that happened in a particular month and if thats blank, get the last time it was filled in"

But that isn't quite whats happening in your query, so I want to confirm the goal.

Comment: @hcaelxxam That is intentional. Any record before 2023 should pull the earliest populated value regardless of date. Any record from 2023 onward should only pull the value tied to it's month, even if it's blank. We only started backing up our H table in January, so it was decided that all records before that would use the earliest populated value to "get close".

Comment: @siggemannen we use SQL Server 2016

Comment: Use an `OUTER APPLY` https://dbfiddle.uk/h3CCPQYV

Comment: voting for reopen

Comment: @philipxy seems to have sample data and results now

Comment: @JackMorris since this got closed, please bear with the tight explanation. using CTEs, do a union of H and History, to have them in the same table.  Then in another CTE, unpivot History for each of the labor/weight fields; this will remove nulls. Then do a SELECT DISTINCT material, measure, FIRST_VALUE(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Material, Measure ORDER BY Mth DESC).  This will get the first amount for each measure/material combination.  Pivot that back to get them in columns again.  Then Join I to the union table (U) to the unpivot/pivot (P).  Then do I Join U Join P; ISNULL(U.Labor, P.Labor)

Comment: @JackMorris can you please show 2 or 3 field implementations. Just saying _"this repeated X times"_ leave us to guess what substitutions to make, showing 2 implementations means we can see what is constant and what is variable.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller added implementation for Labor and Weight, hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the subquery into an `APPLY` and use `SELECT TOP 1`

```sql
SELECT 
    I.Mth, I.Material,

    - - -
    SUM(I.Units * ISNULL(ISNULL(H.SqFt, HH.SqFt), HH1.SqFt)) AS [Total SqFt]
    - - - This section gets repeated for 30 different fields

FROM I
LEFT JOIN H
   ON I.Material = H.Material
  AND I.Mth >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)
LEFT JOIN HHistory HH
   ON I.Mth = H.Mth
  AND I.Material = HHistory.Material
  AND H.SqFt IS NULL
  AND I.Mth >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1)
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 SqFt
    FROM HHistory Sub
    WHERE Sub.Material = I.Material
      AND Sub.SqFt IS NOT NULL
      AND HH.SqFt IS NULL
    ORDER BY Sub.KeyID
) HH1
GROUP BY I.Material, I.Mth
```

Note also how I have made each join dependent on the result of the previous, and then used `ISNULL` to get the result. Do that *inside* the `SUM` and then you don't need to add it to the `GROUP BY`.